# Object instance without new?

Tags: java, oop, constructor, instantiation

As we know we can instantiate an object without `new` keyword by using classloader/object cloning/object serialization. When I am using these techniques to create an object, is the constructor called or not?

Comment: you can always write a class that writes something to console in constructor and try all the technique. Be experimenter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Object.clone` no constructor is called.

For serialisation, the most derived non-serialisable base-class no-arg constructor is called. Typically implemented by loading bytecode that does not validate. The constructor must be accessible to the base-most serialisable class.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know all the three use the constructor even serialization.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

> The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this is not the case

Comment: Where does that quote come from?  You should (ideally) provide a link or else supply a citation.

Comment: I think this citation only applies to subclasses of non-serializable classes. In that case the super-class has to declare a no-argument constructor. The fields of the serializable class itself are initialised without calling the constructor.